# Pronunciation of "vial"

Tags: pronunciation, dialect

According to my dictionary, the word *vial* should be pronounced /vaiəl/. But I've heard the pronunciation /faiəl/. Is that a mistake or merely a dialect?

Comment: See [phial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phial), another term for vial.  They mean the same thing, but you can compare usage with [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vial%2C+phial&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvial%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVIAL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cphial%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bphial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPhial%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Alright! So the pronunciation /f.../ relates to a word with a separate spelling, but the same meaning. Interesting. (Now, if you'll turn your comment into an answer, I'll acknowledge it as the answer to my question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, there are in fact two words in English -- [vial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vial) and [phial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phial).  The meanings are identical, though as a native speaker I will admit that they "feel" a little different.  Namely, *phial* feels a little old-fashioned; maybe because the *ph* makes it look closer to Greek.  It feels right to me that modern scientists put their liquids in vials; but alchemists of the Middle Ages definitely would have used phials.

[Google ngrams seems to support this feeling of old-fashioned-ness.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vial%2C%20phial&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvial%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVIAL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cphial%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bphial%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPhial%3B%2Cc0)  American English has fairly consistently preferred *vial*.  British English preferred *phial* until about 1840, but since 1960 or so *vial* has taken hold.  English fiction also preferred *phial* until about 1970 -- perhaps because it adds "atmosphere" to the story.

Etymologically, the words are, as one might imagine, closely related -- [both came from Old French *fiole*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phial&allowed_in_frame=0).  But *phial* isn't actually older -- [the two variants are about equally old](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vial&allowed_in_frame=0), both appearing in the late 14th century.

Comment: Because "phial" is archaic, writers of fantasy and related fiction seem to prefer it over "vial".  This is why it might show up as often as it does after 1970.